# Ubuntu 14.10 compatibility with Radeon HD 6450

Tags: drivers, 14.10, radeon

My Graphics card is a Radeon HD 6450 and I am having some problems with it and I am trying to figure out if I need a new graphics card.

I am on Ubuntu 64-bit 14.10

First of all, webGL stuff seems not to work. I have it enabled in Chrome and in Firefox and it seems not to work in either. In both of them it is hit or miss. I tend not to be able to view the 3D stuff.

I also have problem when I hover over links where it is supposed to display the full description, it looks all funky sometimes.
For example:
[image]

I am using the Open source driver which is the recommended one. Using proprietary drivers seems to exacerbate the problem.

Does anyone have a solution for me? I don't want to buy a new graphics card and then find out its either incompatible or have the same problem. I'm a total noob in this area.

Comment: Your graphics card is clearly not broken so you should definitely not get a new card. Have you tried booting Ubuntu 14.04 live and seeing if the problem occurs?

Comment: I think the pop-up thing is related to updating to 14.10 from 14.04, but the web-GL stuff was happening when i was still on 14.04.      I know its not broken per-say, but I really need to use webGL